# If/else statements and do while loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

**I'm working on an assignment for school and I can't get past the playerTurn method because the do while part will not compile for me.  This is what I have written:**

```
public class Pig {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Random generator = new Random();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int roll = diceRoll(generator);
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);


}
public static int diceRoll(Random generator){
    int num = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    return num;
}
public static int playerTurn(java.util.Scanner input, java.util.Random rand){
    int turnScore = 0;
    int roll;
    String response;

    do {
        roll = diceRoll(generator);
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);

        if ( roll == 1) {
            turnScore = 0;
            System.out.println("Oh no! You rolled a 1 which means your turn is over and your score is 0");
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Do you want to roll again? Yes or No");
            response = console.next();
        } while (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            return turnScore;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**The compiling errors I keep getting are:**

Pig.java:35: error: while expected
                }
                 ^

Pig.java:37: error: illegal start of expression
}
^

Pig.java:37: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^

Pig.java:40: error: reached end of file while parsing

4 errors

**I'm pretty sure all my brackets match up but I don't know how to fix it if it's not that.  Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Your braces are wrong. The while condition is after the closing } which closes the ```else``` statement on line 30 when it should be after the closing } on line 33.

Comment: A `do/while` statement is not suppose to have brackets... just `while(condition);`  just like that for the while

Comment: Also, your ```return turnScore;``` on line 31 is at the wrong place, you can't put it in a while statement, you need to put it at the end of the method,

Comment: A good code editor such as Sublime Text or Nitrous.io would help when matching start and end braces. When your cursor is near a { or a } the matching brace will glow.

Answer (score 0):

Here this will compile for ya.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pig
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int roll = diceRoll(generator);
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);

  }
  public static int diceRoll(Random generator)
  {
     int num = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
     return num;
  }

  public static int playerTurn(java.util.Scanner input, java.util.Random rand)
  {
      int turnScore = 0;
      int roll;
      String response;

      do 
      {
          roll = diceRoll(rand);
          System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);

          if ( roll == 1) 
          {
              turnScore = 0;
              System.out.println("Oh no! You rolled a 1 which means your turn is over and your score is 0");
              return turnScore;
          } 
          else 
          {
              System.out.println("Do you want to roll again? Yes or No"); 
              response = input.next();
          } 
      }while (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
     return turnScore;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please put the `while` on the same line as the end-brace, otherwise it looks like a new `while` loop with an empty body.